# Collision detection script fails sometimes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, collision-detection, path-finding

For the most part this script works, however every now and then an enemy will fail at pathfinding and go through a building or wall. Is there a way i can stop this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace Daniel {
    public class EnemyAI : Living {

        // Detection private int range = 10; private float speed = 10f; private bool isThereAnyThing = false;

        // Waypoints/Targets
        public GameObject[] targets;
        private float rotationSpeed = 900f;
        private RaycastHit hit;
        GameObject target;
        [SerializeField]
        private int randomTarget = 0;
        [SerializeField]
        float timeToNextCheck = 3;
        public float effectTimer = 2f;
        public GameObject deathEffect;
        public LayerMask detectThis;

        void Start()
        {
            randomTarget = Random.Range(0, 8);
            target = targets[randomTarget];
        }
        void FixedUpdate()
        {
            timeToNextCheck = timeToNextCheck - Time.deltaTime;
            ScanForNewWaypoint();
            LookAtTarget();
            Move();
            CheckForObsticales();
        }
        void LookAtTarget()
        {
            //Look At Somthly Towards the Target if there is nothing in front.
            if (!isThereAnyThing)
            {
                Vector3 relativePos = target.transform.position - transform.position;
                Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos);
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
        void Move()
        {
            // Enemy translate in forward direction.
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        }
        public void CheckForObsticales()
        {
            //Checking for any Obstacle in front.
            // Two rays left and right to the object to detect the obstacle.
            Transform leftRay = transform;
            Transform rightRay = transform;
            //Use Phyics.RayCast to detect the obstacle
            if (Physics.Raycast(leftRay.position + (transform.right * 7f), transform.forward, out hit, range, detectThis) || Physics.Raycast(rightRay.position - (transform.right * 7f), transform.forward, out hit, range))
            {
                if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Obstacles"))
                {
                    isThereAnyThing = true;
                    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
                }
            }
            // Now Two More RayCast At The End of Object to detect that object has already pass the obsatacle.
            // Just making this boolean variable false it means there is nothing in front of object.
            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position - (transform.forward * 4), transform.right, out hit, 10, detectThis) ||
                Physics.Raycast(transform.position - (transform.forward * 4), -transform.right, out hit, 10, detectThis))
            {
                if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Obstacles"))
                {
                    isThereAnyThing = false;
                }
            }
        }
        public void ScanForNewWaypoint()
        {
            CheckForObsticales();
            if (timeToNextCheck <= 0)
            {
                timeToNextCheck = Random.Range(6, 3);
                randomTarget = Random.Range(0, 8);
                target = targets[randomTarget];
            }
        }
        public override void TakeHit(float dmg, Vector3 hitPoint, Vector3 hitDirection)
        {
            if (dmg >= health)
            {
                Destroy(Instantiate(deathEffect, hitPoint, Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.forward, hitDirection)) as GameObject, effectTimer);
                Debug.Log("Exploded");
            }
            base.TakeHit(dmg, hitPoint, hitDirection);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This may not be appropriate practice... but do you still have issues if you change `FixedUpdate()` to `Update()`?

Comment: Try to set your rigidbody collision detection from Discrete to Continuos

Comment: I might be wrong but you are doing only 4 raycasts in the main directions, so maybe the raycasts are just missing the obstacle (raycast that goes above or under the obstacle etc...).

Answer (score 0):

Okay now this is one of the most common problems people face when playing with **Physics Engine** and believe me there are lot of factors that adds up to the result/consequences you are facing. Most common solutions devised by people is to use **Update** which is **Executed Every Frame** for Physics calculation which is **Entirely Wrong**. All the physics related calculation needs to be performed inside the **Fixed Update** otherwise it will be too expensive to execute physics based simulations in the **Update** which means every single frame. In your case where your **Enemy** is going through walls and Physics Collisions are missing the best solution you can take is to tweak some **Physics Related Properties in Unity** these are located in **Edit>>>Project Settings>>>Time** change the **Time Step and Maximum Allowed Time Step** in the inspector to set your collisions right. There are some other things to keep in mind too while dealing with physics like scale, mass and colliders etc. Here is a [Link](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/learn-physics-optimization-in-unity-easily) concerning the detailed mechanics of the physics settings in unity. Make sure you read and understand the contents of the link before working and tweaking physics settings.